# launch an automatic action once connected to a specific ssid on OS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, bash, automation

My college requires a local gateway authentication webpage after connecting to their wifi, so I would like to make my macbook pro to automatically run curl with the proper user and password when I connect to their wifi ssid. I am not sure where I would check the ssid in bash, or what utility would automatically launch a command on connection to a certain ssid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) that can do things like this. There is also [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), which allows you to run scripts on sleep/wake (which is usually when i find myself changing Wi-Fi networks anyway). And then there is always just having a `cron` or `launchd` job run periodically.

I've never used MarcoPolo, but if you go one of the other routes, you can get the name of the Wi-Fi network with this command:

```
networksetup -getairportnetwork en1
```

(Replace `en1` by your Wi-Fi interface name)